# Get query Id in websql mock in ionic 3 (to reuse in other query)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, web-sql

Currently I'm new to ionic (3) and I'm trying to build an app with database support (so the user can use the app when he is offline).
But I have a problem, and I can't get my head around it why it works like this.

What I did.
My set up is an ionic3 app on the Angular 5 framework.
For the app on device I use the sqlite plugin of ionic it self, but I want to mock the plugin so I can test in the browser. So this is my code for the mock.

```
export class SQLiteMock {
public create(config: SQLiteDatabaseConfig): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
    let db = (<any> window).openDatabase(config.name, '1.0', 'test database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(new SQLiteObject(db));
    });
}}


// ------Init call from component------------------------
init(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.sqlite.create({
                name: 'test.db',
                location: 'default'
            }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                this.db = db;
            });
        }
    );
}
```

So far so good. When I run this it works on device and on web. Even when I create the tables everything shows up correctly.
The problem is when I insert a query in the db with the next code:

```
executeSql(queryStatement: string, params?: Array<string | number>): Promise<any> {
    params = params ? params : [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(queryStatement, params,
                (tx, result) => {
                    console.log(result);   //-->  console: SQLResultSet {rows: SQLResultSetRowList, insertId: 5, rowsAffected: 1}
                    console.log(Object.assign({}, result));   //--> console: {}
                    resolve(result);
                },
                (error) => reject(error));
        });
    });
}
```

What I want to do is use the insertedId of the first query, and use it in the next one. But as you can see, when the promise goes off, the result is still empty, so next query will fail because there is no Id.

Does anybody know why I have this timeing issue?
And how can I fix it that the promise waits to get resolved until the result is there?

Already many thanks for your help, because I'm really stuck with this.

Kind regards

Function who calls the function

```
execQuery(query: string, params?: Array<string | number>): Promise<number> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.db.executeSql(query, params)
        .then((result: any) => {
            resolve(result.insertId);    //--> result = {}
        })
        .catch((e) => reject(e));
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your second console.log instruction dispays an empty object({}) seems related to Object.assign() function rather than a WebSQL issue. According to the [documentation of Object.assign() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn858229(v=vs.94).aspx), only own enumerable properties are copied from source object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if this was the case, then I would get the id in the function who call's it... not?

`execQuery(query: string, params?: Array<string | number>): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.executeSql(query, params)
            .then((result: any) => {
                resolve(result.insertId);    //--> still null
            })
            .catch((e) => reject(e));
    });
}`
And there I have no Id either....
And that's the problem because I need this id to input the next query..

Comment: What about simplifying your calling function this way:
`execQuery(query: string, params?: Array<string | number>): Promise<number> {
return this.db.executeSql(query, params)
.then((result: any) => {
 console.dir(result);
 return result.insertId;
})
.catch((e) => reject(e));
})`

Comment: Just tried your solution to simplify my function... Strange but true, now it works... I have no idea why this is different from mine, but thank you very much!!!

Comment: I think it was due to the execution context "this" of your call to this.db.executeSql().